# Alternate Major Tick Lengths on X-axis in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way in which I can alternate the length of the major ticks on my x-axis - say between `length` = `7` and `length` = `2` - such that I can *reduce the length of my x axis* and make my figure more aesthetically pleasing? The linked image shows what my axes currently look like

[image: Current Plot]